# How to split multiple audio files by 10 seconds each on OSX?

Tags: bash, macos, ffmpeg

Let's say I have 100 audio files and I would like to split each file into several files with 10 seconds length.

I think the following should work:

```
for i in *.ogg; do
  echo -n $i ...
  ffmpeg -i $i.ogg -ss 0  -t 10 $i_1.ogg
  ffmpeg -i $i.ogg -ss 10 -t 10 $i_2.ogg
  ffmpeg -i $i.ogg -ss 20 -t 10 $i_3.ogg
done
```

But I don't understand how many times ffmpeg commands should be repeated.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the segment muxer.

```
for i in *.ogg; do
  echo -n $i ...
  ffmpeg -i "$i" -c copy -vn -f segment -segment_time 10 $i_%d.ogg
done
```

Comment: Consider double quoting `"$i_%d.ogg"` so that files with spaces work too.